# How can i have output that write different or missing element in array?

Tags: java, arrays

When I run this, I can see exact result "false" but I also want to see what difference there is. For instance

> "ozer and gunthy" match but "albundy and aldy" does not

```
package start;

public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        String[] a = {"ozer + gunthy + albundy"};
        String[] b = {"ozer + günthy + aldy"};

        boolean b1 = false;

        if (a.length != b.length){
            b1 = false;
        }else {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
                if (a[i] == b[i]){
                    b1 = true;
                }else {
                    b1 = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(b1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean: `String[] a = {"ozer", "gunthy", "albundy"};`?

Comment: See also: [How do I compare strings in Java?](//stackoverflow.com/q/513832)

Comment: Strings should also be compared using a[i].equals(b[i]) and not ==

Comment: thank you for your help, i appreciate it...

Answer (score 0):

You will want to replace

> `a[i] == b[i]`

with

```
a[i].equals(b[i])
```

You will also need to fix your arrays

```
public static String[] list1 = {"ozer", "gunthy","albundy"};
public static String[] list2 = {"ozer", "günthy","aldy"};
```

then, you will need to write and call a method to properly analyze the arrays to your specification:

```
public String methodName(String[] list1, String[] list2)
{
    String output = "";
    if (list1.length != list2.length)
    {
        return "The Arrays differ in length";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++)
        {
            if (list1[i].equals(list2[i]))
            {
                output += "" + list1[i] + " is equal to " + list2[i] + "\n";
            }
            else 
            {
                output += "" + list1[i] + " is not equal to " + list2[i] + "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```